# Lucene WildcardTermEnum

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

```
Dim terms As New WildcardTermEnum(index_reader, New Term("filename", "*" + search_box.Text + "*"))

    While terms.[Next]()
                Dim currentTerm As Term = terms.Term()
                Dim value As [String] = currentTerm.Text()
    End While
```

i have two fields  "filename" and "id"

i can get  value of "filename" field by using the above code but i  want to get value of id field in while loop..

for example;

filename:"TEST" and id:"10"

using above code i can get "TEST" string but i want to get id value related to filename field..

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply run a search with a single TermQuery using `currentTerm`. You can get the ids from the results.

Better yet, bypass the WildcardTermEnum and run a wildcard search. Because there is limited support for wildcards at the start of the term, you may want to consider using a [SpanWildcardQuery](http://code.ohloh.net/file?fid=2oZabcXGG18SPjiYjap5RoZ-Md8&cid=LZilCEks83E&s=spanwildcardquery&mp=1&ml=1&me=1&md=1&browser=Default#L30).

Comment: Thx for helping but i cant use SpanWildcardQuery with dotnet..using another termquery in loop to get id field is causing performance problem:/

Comment: It's true that currently there's no SpanWildcardQuery in .NET but with a trivial amount of work you can take the Java version I linked to and port it to .NET. I think you'll find much better performance using this approach.

Comment: I guess using termquery in loop is the only way of solving my problem for now.. thx for tips